# Go http.ResponseWriter.Write does not return error when client closed connection

Tags: http, go

I wrote a simple http HandleFunc that take 2 seconds to process, then I send a request with 1 second timeout to the server. I expect that calling ResponseWriter.Write will return an error, but it does not. Please explain this for me.

Server code:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    log.SetFlags(log.Ltime | log.Lshortfile)

    handler := http.NewServeMux()
    handler.HandleFunc("/long-task",
        func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            go func() {
                <-r.Context().Done()
                log.Println("client closed or server responded")
            }()
            log.Println("handling long-task")
            time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
            n, err := w.Write([]byte("my slow response"))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("error when ResponseWriter Write: ", err)
            }
            log.Printf("responded to long-task. n: %v\n", n)
        })
    server := &http.Server{Addr: ":8008", Handler: handler}

    log.Println("listening on port ", server.Addr)
    err := server.ListenAndServe()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Client code:

```
package main

import (
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    client := http.Client{Timeout: 1 * time.Second}
    r, _ := http.NewRequest("GET", "http://127.0.0.1:8008/long-task", nil)
    w, err := client.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer w.Body.Close()
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(w.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Printf("response: %s\n", body)
}
```

Server output:

```
10:50:58 http_server.go:28: listening on port  :8008
10:51:01 http_server.go:19: handling long-task
10:51:02 http_server.go:17: client closed or server responded
10:51:03 http_server.go:25: responded to long-task. n: 16
```

Client output:

```
2020/05/27 10:51:02 Get "http://127.0.0.1:8008/long-task": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

Comment: "I expect that calling ResponseWriter.Write will return an error" Your expectation is wrong. That simply is not how HTTP works. What is your question? Note that you _cannot_ (really!) detect that the client did not read your response.

Comment: I can know when client disconnect from request context. I ask where the  writer write to if client closed

Comment: That is exactly the same. The server cannot  know.

Comment: Writes are typically buffered. Your handler is probably writing into the buffer, but the buffer contents cannot be sent to the client once the connection is closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too little data has been written, ResponseWriter did not send the buffered data to the client.

```golang
    handler.HandleFunc("/long-task", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        go func() {
            <-r.Context().Done()
            log.Println("client closed or server responded")
        }()
        log.Println("handling long-task")
        time.Sleep(2 * time.Second)
        for i := 0; i < 520; i++ {
            _, err := w.Write([]byte("my slow response"))
            if err != nil {
                log.Println("error when ResponseWriter Write: ", err, i)
            }
        }
        // log.Printf("responded to long-task. n: %v\n", n)
    })
```

srv out:

```
13:53:19 01.go:30: listening on port  :8008
13:53:22 01.go:18: handling long-task
13:53:23 01.go:16: client closed or server responded
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 512
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 513
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 514
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 515
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 516
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 517
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 518
13:53:24 01.go:23: error when ResponseWriter Write:  write tcp 127.0.0.1:8008->127.0.0.1:57098: write: broken pipe 519
```

Comment: Can you help me always get an error when calling ResponseWriter.Write on closed connection?

Comment: No, Write writes data to bufio.Buffer. Only when buf fills up or ServeHTTP ends, it will write to net.Conn for network transmission. The http.Flusher interface did not return error.
You can ignore the error, why must ResponseWriter.Write return error?

Comment: sometime the server want to rollback the long task if it cannot respond to the client

Comment: It is recommended to use websocket or grpc, http is the request/response format. Or polling regularly